# Sustituir palabra array javascript con función y for

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for, function

estoy aprendiendo en JavaScript y haciendo un ejercicio me he topado con un problema que no consigo resolver.

Básicamente el enunciado dice que debo sustituir la palabra "sad" de cualquier frase que se introduzca por "Happy".
Lo he logrado hacer de esta forma, pero cuando introduces más de un input, no funciona:

```
function xd(text) {
return text.replace("sad", "happy")
}
xd("Clowns were sad sad sad")
```

Ante la curiosidad, he tratado de hacerlo con un bucle for que según el planteamiento que tengo en mi cabeza debería repetir el return sustituyendo sad por happy pero...me da valor undefined, y no sé por qué.

```js
function xd (text) {
    for (i = 0; i < text.lenght; i++){
        return text.replace("sad", "happy");
    }
}
console.log(xd("The clowns were sad"));
```

Si alguien me pudiera echar una mano, disculpad si es algo extremadamente fácil.

Un saludo, y gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes! Te recomiendo leer [ask] y completar el [tour]. Una buena pregunta siempre muestra código como texto, nunca como imágenes. La forma más sencilla de obtener respuestas es permitir a los usuarios copiar el código desde la pregunta, pegarlo en la respuesta y modificarlo para añadir una solución o explicar el problema o duda.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dos opciones sencillas:

- Usar `replace` con expresiones regulares y añadir el *flag* `g`,
- Usar `replaceAll`

```js
function replace(text) {
  return text.replace(/sad/g, "happy")
}

function replaceAll(text) {
return text.replaceAll("sad", "happy")
}
console.log(replace("Clowns were sad sad sad"))

console.log(replaceAll("Clowns were sad sad sad"))
```

Lo bueno de usar replaceAll es que no necesitas usar regex, lo que puede ser más complicado cuando quieres parametrizar el campo a buscar.

---

Ahora te explico por qué tu código no funciona: tienes una errata que hace que el bucle no se ejecute, con lo que no se devuelve nada:

```javascript
function xd (text) {
  for (i = 0; i < text.lenght; i++){ // errata, es length
    return text.replace("sad", "happy");
  }
}
console.log(xd("The clowns were sad sad"));
```

Aún así hay un problema más: si pones un return dentro de un bucle, el bucle sólo se puede ejecutar una vez:

```js
function xd (text) {
  for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    console.log("ejecutando");
    return text.replace("sad", "happy");
  }
}
console.log(xd("The clowns were sad sad "));
```

Aún así, lo correcto sería repetir mientras la cadena a sustituir exista, no durante la longitud de la misma. Por tanto, arreglando todo podrías haber hecho algo como:

```js
function xd2 (text) {
  while (text.includes("sad")) {
    text = text.replace("sad", "happy");
  }
  return text;
}
console.log(xd2("The clowns were sad sad "));
```

Answer (score 1):

Si sustituyes la cadena `"sad"` por la expresión regular `/sad/g` conseguirás tu propósito:

```js
function xd(text) {
  return text.replace(/sad/g, "happy")
}
console.log(xd("Clowns were sad sad sad"))
```

### Explicación

- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) soporta tanto cadenas como expresiones regulares
- `/sad/g` es una expresión regular que indica:

  **/sad/**:  Cadena a buscar (delimitada por **/**)

  **g**: de forma global en todas las coincidencias que encuentre

Answer (score 0):

Podes cambiar el bucle FOR por WHILE y el replace por un replaceAll asi:

```
function xd (text) {
while(text.includes('sad')){
    return text.replaceAll("sad", "happy");
    }
}
xd("The clowns were sad sad sad");
```